# how to show latest posts from each category in drop down menu

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, menu

I have added a drop down menu to my wordpress theme.  I've got it installed and it works fine.  However, now I would like to display the latest posts from each category in drop down menu. Can anyone help point me in the right direction.

an example of what I'm looking for
[image]

Here is the current code of my drop down menu

```html
class CSS_Menu_Walker extends Walker {
 
var $db_fields = array('parent' => 'menu_item_parent', 'id' => 'db_id');
function start_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = array()) {
$indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
$output .= "\n$indent<ul>\n";
}
function end_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = array()) {
$indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
$output .= "$indent</ul>\n";
}
function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0) {
global $wp_query;
$indent = ($depth) ? str_repeat("\t", $depth) : '';
$class_names = $value = '';
$classes = empty($item->classes) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
/* Add active class */
if (in_array('current-menu-item', $classes)) {
$classes[] = 'active';
unset($classes['current-menu-item']);
}
/* Check for children */
$children = get_posts(array('post_type' => 'nav_menu_item', 'nopaging' => true, 'numberposts' => 1, 'meta_key' => '_menu_item_menu_item_parent', 'meta_value' => $item->ID));
if (!empty($children)) {
$classes[] = 'has-sub';
}
$class_names = join(' ', apply_filters('nav_menu_css_class', array_filter($classes), $item, $args));
$class_names = $class_names ? ' class="' . esc_attr($class_names) . '"' : '';
$id = apply_filters('nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-'. $item->ID, $item, $args);
$id = $id ? ' id="' . esc_attr($id) . '"' : '';
$output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $value . $class_names .'>';
$attributes  = ! empty($item->attr_title) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr($item->attr_title) .'"' : '';
$attributes .= ! empty($item->target)     ? ' target="' . esc_attr($item->target    ) .'"' : '';
$attributes .= ! empty($item->xfn)        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr($item->xfn       ) .'"' : '';
$attributes .= ! empty($item->url)        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr($item->url       ) .'"' : '';
$item_output = $args->before;
$item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'><span>';
$item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters('the_title', $item->title, $item->ID) . $args->link_after;
$item_output .= '</span></a>';
$item_output .= $args->after;
$output .= apply_filters('walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args);
}
function end_el(&$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array()) {
$output .= "</li>\n";
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This method uses the built-in wp_get_recent_posts function. All you need to do is copy and paste the following code in your theme’s functions.php file or a site-specific plugin.

```
function wpb_recentposts_dropdown() { 
$string .= '<select id="rpdropdown">
    <option  value="" selected>Select a Post<option>';

$args = array( 'numberposts' => '5', 'post_status' => 'publish' );

$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts($args);
    foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
        $string .= '<option value="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '">' .   $recent["post_title"].'</option> ';
}

$string .= '</select>
    <script type="text/javascript"> var urlmenu = document.getElementById( "rpdropdown" ); urlmenu.onchange = function() {
        window.open( this.options[ this.selectedIndex ].value, "_self" );
     };
    </script>';

return $string;
} 
add_shortcode('rp_dropdown', 'wpb_recentposts_dropdown');
add_filter('widget_text','do_shortcode');
```

Comment: But will this allow me to add the posts inside the drop down menu like in the above example?